# Como extrair a parte numérica de um valor monetário?

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho uma string com os caracteres "R$ 1.000,60" e gostaria de extrair somente os caracteres "1.000,60".

Tentei usar expressão regular, mas não consegui alcançar o meu objetivo. Cheguei nisso:

```
    string valor = "";
    string texto = "R$ 1.000,60";

    Regex r = new Regex(@"^[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?$");
    foreach (Match m in r.Matches(texto))
        valor += m.Value;
```

Alguém saberia resolver esse problema usando expressão regular ou outra técnica?

Comment: +1 inclusive pela boa vontade do edit :) Já temos uma solução boa com Regex, e podem surgir mais alternativas para você, do Cigano mesmo e/ou de outros usuários.

Comment: Um split não seria suficiente?

Comment: É garantido que o formato é sempre começando com `R$ ` e depois vem o número que interessa no formato apresentado?

Comment: Nem sempre os valores vão começar com R$, podendo alterar também as ordens dos campos, como por exemplo 50R$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifique para o seguinte:

```
 var r = new Regex(@"[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{3})*(,[0-9]{2})?$");
```

[Aqui está um exemplo funcional da expressão regular](http://regexr.com/39oda).

Comment: Por que o uso de `var` e não `Regex`?

Comment: O compilador é capaz de intuir qual o tipo da variável a ser devolvida.